Is it possible to redirect the content of a wildmenu to a variable?
Say that I type :cd <tab>. I get displayed a menu with all the directories in pwd. I am wondering if I can store the content of such a menu into a variable.
For example, if :cd <tab> displays
foo/
bar/baz/
another/dir/

then I wish to store these values in a var x such that :echo x returns ['foo/', 'bar/baz/', 'another/dir'].
Is it possible? And if so, how?

I can answer by myself: yes, it is possible. The function for achieving that is :h getcompletion(). However, note that the operation is blocking, in the sense that if the completion list is large, then getcompletion() may take long time, thus freezing Vim.

Hi @Barzi2001, maybe could you share the full answer to help others with the same question.

Sure! I will do later!
